# Is it normal for a DAI vault to cost between $80 - $160 in gas fees?

Tags: gas-price, dai, stablecoins

I am trying to open a Vault for the first time with ETH-A as collateral.

Do the below fees make sense? They seem quite expensive to me ...

[image]

Additionally I see this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gas price of 129 gWei and gas limit of almost 1 million the numbers you stated are correct. You can try the calculations yourself at https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php .

Note that the gas limit is only the upper limit to how much gas the transaction is allowed to spend: it does not necessarily mean that the transaction uses that much gas, but it might. So the exact "gas usage" of the transaction is only known after it has executed. Your client is doing its best to try to estimate the gas usage for you but sometimes the estimates are simply wrong, due to various reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I thought that it may be due to the complexity of the code too. As a user of this, how can i find the "gas price used and the estimated gas usage"?
I updated my answer to reflect what else I see (the gas price and gas limit).

Comment: Edited to add more details

Comment: Thanks! If I am not pressed for time, is there a way where I can optimize this?

Comment: You can give an arbitrarily low gas price, but the transaction may never get through.

Comment: Okay, so it's advisable to keep as is I guess?

Comment: At least the lowest offered option ("Slow"), yes